# Telerik, center the text of a RadDropDownList with DropDownList style enabled?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, telerik

I'm trying to center the text that is displayed in the control (not in the menu), but I can't find the way to do this when the `DropDownStyle` property is set to `DropDownList` mode.

[image]

Seems that the UI element `RadTextBoxItem\TextAllign` only affects when the `DropDownStyle` property is set to `DropDown` mode:

[image]

How I can fix this?

Comment: I cant find a `TextAlign` property for the DDL and dont understand how/why the TextBoxItem is involved

Comment: @Plutonix I've uploaded an image showing that, when that property is set to "Center" the selected item text is centered, that works for 'DropDown' mode but not for a 'DropDownList' mode.

Comment: the text "cuotas de partido" is inside a RadtextBox (I mean by default, i did not added a RadTextbox of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the UI elements you referenced are (mainly) for tweaking the drop down items.

Use the `TextAlignment` Property on the Items.  In the form designer, pick `Edit Items`.  Add your items using `DescriptionTextListDataItems` and set the text and `TextAlignment` property.  If you add `RadListDataItems` it will work the same except the dropdown list portion will also be centered.

[image]

There might (ought) be a way to set defaults or one for all - I cant imagine anyone wanting each to be different - such as via the UI Elements hive you were tweaking, but those dont seem to flow thru or map to the text portion.

In code, if you just add strings to the `items` collection, it will use defaults, so add `Description....` objects:

```
Dim mi As New DescriptionTextListDataItem
mi.Text = "Over-engineered"
mi.TextAlignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter

RadDropDownList1.Items.Add(mi)
```

Be sure to use `Text` not `DescriptionText` or the item will be disabled.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks but that will affect also to the expanded menu, my intention is only center the text displayed of the textbox, not the text of the menu which is displayed when clicking the arrow. my words: `I'm trying to center the text that is displayed in the control (not in the menu)`

Comment: Anyways, in the other hand, I need to say that with your suggestion and with the help of the 'SelectedIndexChanged' and 'SelectedIndexChanging' events when I select an item I turn it to 'centered' and the other non-selected items as 'middleLeft', the problem is that, the same problem described, the centered selected-item is also centered in the dropdown menu, I mean in the list items.

Comment: Not on my system; see image in edit.  I believe those UI Elements have a hand in how things are displayed in the drop down.  As I said in the answer, ListDataItems will display that way, but not the others (Description...).  I cant believe that is thew main difference between them, but it is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
Private Sub RadDropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As Data.PositionChangedEventArgs) _
Handles RadDropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged

    sender.DropDownListElement.
           EditableElement.
           TextAlignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter

End Sub
```

This way I can set my list items with middle-left allignment and showing the selected item text centered :)

PS: yes I need to set the allignment every time that the selectedinex has changed.